# Unknow Option error while file copying from EC2 to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have some files in ec2 instance and i want to transfer them to s3.

File name :

```
sequence_01.txt
sequence_02.txt
sequence_03.txt
abcd.txt
asda.txt
rasdg.txt
```

I want to copy files starting with sequence.
Command i'm trying to copy

```
aws s3 cp sequence*.txt s3://bucketname/
```

error

```
Error : unknown option sequence*.txt does not exist.
```

If i want to copy all files starting with sequence to s3 bucket.how can i transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy your files using [--include and --exclude](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters) filters.

For example:

```
aws s3 cp . s3://bucketname/ --recursive  --exclude "*" --include "sequence*.txt"
```

or with `sync`

```
aws s3 sync . s3://bucketname/ --exclude "*" --include "sequence*.txt"
```